# setting up eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just started learning java. I downloaded eclipse for linux and had an error for which I then followed scott's advice and typed **:**

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```

Which seemed to help. I want to know that which java should I use?

[click on link to see my options](http://shortText.com/tlu5AiB)

Also, once I have the .class file, how can I run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use HotSpot impl for java(It seems you have open-jdk), so install it following to this url: http://ubuntu-for-humans.blogspot.com/2011/04/installing-java-on-ubuntu-server-1010.html.  And use jdk, not jre. 
Once you run eclipse, eclipse does for you everything: compiles, runs, deployes, IDE, ...

Comment: Hi, When I type java -version I get this java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode) is that what I'm looking for? also, how can I open up .class files?

Comment: It seems it is jre, not JDK, jre for  running java apps, jdk is for developing them. You need jdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the java version for the linux [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml)

Setting up of eclipse shouldn't be a problem but make sure that java is installed first.

Comment: Yeah, I have java selected. Which once Should I use? OpenJDK? Oracle java?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html     download jdk